# Change the 'Name' of content using the content service

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco7

I am having some difficulty changing the name of my nodes using the ContentService in Umbraco v7.1.6.

I have tried the following:

```
umbraco_node.SetValue("Name", web_service_item.Keyword);
umbraco_node.SetValue("name", web_service_item.Keyword);
```

My content is coming from a web service that integrates with a desktop based system and therefore I need to ensure that the name given in the desktop software always corresponds to what is presented on the web. How do I change the standard Umbraco 'Name' property in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For changing Node Name you have to do something like that :

```
    umbraco_node.Name = "32";
    contentService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(umbraco_node);
```

Don't forget about publishing node.